# writing out after comparing columns from 2 csv/dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I feel like there is a much intuitive way to do this then with for loops but i am currently stuck. i got a portion of it but filled the rest with psuedocode. Would greatly appreciate some help with this.

```
import pandas as pd
first_df= pd.read_csv('city_states.csv')

second_df = pd.read_csv('locations.csv);

for i in first_df[:,0]: #city column
for j in first_df[:,1] #state column
```

psuedocode

```
if i == second_df[:1]: # state column in second data frame
    and if j == second_df[:2]: # city column in second data frame
```

write the longitude and latitude if a match occures to text file delimted by tab

This is what i am trying to do Currently i am trying to generate longitude and latitude from one csv if it's contained in another csv. Maybe data frames. i am looking in to best option

location.csv

```
zip state   city    lat lng
35004   AL  Acmar   33.584132   -86.51557
35005   AL  Adamsville  33.588437   -86.959727
35006   AL  Adger   33.434277   -87.167455
35007   AL  Keystone    33.236868   -86.812861
35010   AL  New Site    32.941445   -85.951086
5014    AL  Alpine  33.331165   -86.208934
35016   AL  Arab    34.328339   -86.489638
```

if city and state match the city and state of this second csv. We need to create a txt file with those long and latitides delimited by tab, as written in the above psudeocode. First data frame refers to city_state.csv and second data frame referes to locations.csv which contains the long and lat we are trying to extract if there is match

city_state.csv

```
City        State
Burlington  VT
Minneapolis  MN
Bloomington  IN
Irvine  CA
```

expected output

```
 95.64652295    36.70384646 
 72.6535921  23.0519796  
-86.2651028 43.222406   
 55.29835975 25.25033149 
-117.87059452   34.11669299 
-80.26491717    25.80180169
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html) and [`to_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html):

```
print df1
     zip state        city        lat        lng
0  35004    AL       Acmar  33.584132 -86.515570
1  35005    AL  Adamsville  33.588437 -86.959727
2  35006    AL       Adger  33.434277 -87.167455
3  35007    AL    Keystone  33.236868 -86.812861
4  35010    AL     NewSite  32.941445 -85.951086
5   5014    AL      Alpine  33.331165 -86.208934
6  35016    AL        Arab  34.328339 -86.489638

print df2
          City State
0       Alpine    AL
1  Minneapolis    MN
2  Bloomington    IN
3       Irvine    CA

df = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on=['state','city'], right_on=['State','City'])
print df
    zip state    city        lat        lng    City State
0  5014    AL  Alpine  33.331165 -86.208934  Alpine    AL

df[['lat','lng']].to_csv('filename.txt', sep='\t', header=False, index=False)
```

Comment: Please check my solution. For me is little bit unclear `write the longitude and latitude if a match occures to text file delimted by tab`. Do you need write only columns `lan` and `long`? Can you add desired output? And maybe you can little change input, because in your is no matching.

Comment: wow great but i am only looking for lan and long to be written to the text file

Comment: sure just added the expect output